# Can i directly send message to recipient using Twilio WhatsApp api without using join [key-word]. Is it because of Twilio Sandbox?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, whatsapi

Can I directly send message to recipient using Twilio WhatsApp api without using join [key-word].

Is it because of Twilio Sandbox?

If I send request to enable my Twilio number of WhatsApp, issue will get resolved and I can send messages directly?

Answer (score 1):

The `join [key-word]` system is just for the Twilio Sandbox for WhatsApp. It allows Twilio to use one WhatsApp number for all accounts that are testing with the Sandbox.

Once you have [connected your Twilio number to your WhatsApp business profile](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/connect-number-business-profile) you will be able to send messages to your users without requiring them to message you first. Note that [WhatsApp does still require an explicit opt-in from your users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/overview/getting-opt-in) before you can send to them. Also, for initiating conversations you will need to [get template messages approved and then use the template as the first message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-whatsapp-notification-messages-templates). But the technical barrier of the `join` message will not be in your way.

Comment: Also, when you initiate, you would use one of your pre-approved templates to do so.

Comment: Ah, very good point, thanks Alan! I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Philnash and Alan Thanks for your help. 

I want some clarification on "WhatsApp does still require an explicit opt-in from your users" 

This I have to handle on my code level. I mean using web hook I have to store the service "Start" or "Stop" response of the recipient? or this is internally handled by WhatsApp?

Comment: The opt-in is not code, as such, but that you cannot just send messages to your users without getting their permission first. If you [click through the link to the information on the opt-in](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/overview/getting-opt-in) you will see WhatsApp's requirements.